# VBA macro "range.value" causing error

Tags: vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this code

```
Sub ifcitythencity()

If InStr(1, (range("A2").Value), "San Francisco") > 0 Then range.Value("B2") = "San Francisco"

End Sub
```

But when I run the debugger, I get the error "Compile error: Argument not optional," and it highlights the second "range." What's causing this error?

Comment: Try `range("B2").Value = "San fran"`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it describes a problem that went away when a typo was fixed as it is unlikely to help future readers, and because, being about programming, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were using `range.value("B2")` rather than `range("B2").value` -

```
Sub ifcitythencity()

If InStr(1, (range("A2").Value), "San Francisco") > 0 Then range("B2").Value = "San Francisco"

End Sub
```

The error

> argument not optional

gives you the clue as to the problem - the `range(arg)` [object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) **has to** have an argument within the `()`.